# JAX_RS - MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for ArrayList

Tags: java, jboss, jersey, wildfly

I am writing a JAX_RS application using Jersey. All endpoints which return a single object as JSON work fine in Tomcat and WildFly.

One endpoint which returns a collection of objects works absolutely fine in Tomcat. However, when I deploy the same service in WildFly 10.1.0 it fails.

Function is given below:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response searchForActivities(ActivitySearch search) {
    System.out.println(search.getDescriptions() + ", " + search.getDurationFrom());

    List<Activity> activities = activityRepository.findByConstraints(search);

    if(activities == null || activities.size() <= 0) {
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }

    return Response.ok().entity(new GenericEntity<List<Activity>> (activities) {}).build();

}
```

Stack trace is given below:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, a function simply returning `List<Activity>` works in Tomcat and WildFly without any issue. See the definition of the function below:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Activity> getAllActivities() {
    return activityRepository.findAllActivities();
}
```

Comment: Are you using anything specific to Jersey or just the JAX-RS API's?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No, nothing specific to Jersey

Comment: Then try leaving your Jersey dependencies out of your WAR and just using the default implementation provided by WildFly which is RESTEasy.

Comment: Actually, I am following a tutorial on Pluralsight and there the author is using Jersey implementation and Tomcat as webserver, What I want is to run the same example against WildFly.

Comment: Does it use maven or how do you build the WAR? Essentially you just need to make sure that Jersey and the JAX-RS libraries don't end up in your deployment.

Comment: Yes, it uses Maven. I will share the complete source code tomorrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125957/discussion-between-james-r-perkins-and-a-j-qarshi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems to be tied heavily to Jersey. You'd need to modify the POM to use the WildFly BOM (`org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-javaee7-with-tools:10.1.0.Final`). Then import the JAX-RS dependencies or use the [Java EE 7 maven coordinates](https://glassfish.java.net/wiki-archive/Java%20EE%207%20Maven%20Coordinates.html) ([also helpful](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/a_list_of_java_ee)).

If you want a more generic JAX-RS client example that should work with any Java EE 7 complient container have a look at the [WildFly JAX-RS Client quickstart](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/jaxrs-client). Or any of the [Java EE Samples](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs).